# Transfer outlook emails to MS SQL

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

I'm setting up a program that extracts the date, sender, subject and body of emails in my outlook. However, when I run the code it gives me the below error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\zaballgl\Documents\Adhoc\2019\April\ETL_MetricsEmailOutlook.py", line 83, in <module>
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO dbo.BSO_metricsEmailReports([Start_Date],[Name],[Subject],[Body])values(?,?,?,?)",row['Start_Date'],row['Name'],row['Subject'],row['Body'])
    pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('Invalid parameter type.  param-index=1 param-type=CDispatch', 'HY105')
```

This is my code for extracting data from my outlook:

```
    import win32com.client
    import pandas as pd
    import datetime
    import numpy as np
    import pyodbc


    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
    inbox = outlook.Folders('email@outlook.com').Folders('Inbox')

    messages = inbox.Items
    message = messages.GetFirst()
    rec_time = message.CreationTime 
    body_content = message.body
    subj_line = message.subject
    sender = message.Sender


    year=[]
    month=[]
    day=[]
    hour=[]
    minute=[]
    subject=[]
    sender=[]
    body = []


    while message:

    ###This iterates every format of the message.CreationTime and append them to     the list above
    year.append(message.CreationTime.year)
    month.append(message.CreationTime.month)
    day.append(message.CreationTime.day)
    hour.append(message.CreationTime.hour)
    minute.append(message.CreationTime.minute)

    ## Iterates every subject and append them to the subject variable list
    subject.append(message.subject)

    ## Iterates every sender name and append them to the sender variable list
    sender.append(message.Sender)

    ## Iterates every sender name and append them to the sender variable list
    body.append(message.body)

    ## Goes to the next email
    message = messages.GetNext()


    ## This saves all the information to a context manager


    #------COLUMNS FOR THE TABLE---------------#
    #StartDate
    date =    pd.DataFrame({'year':year,'month':month,'day':day,'hour':hour,'minute':minute})     # Had to do this to bypass this error: ValueError: Tz-aware datetime.datetime     cannot be converted to datetime64 unless utc=True
    startDate = pd.to_datetime(date) # Using the above variable this converts     this to dtype: datetime64[ns]

    #Subject
    subject = pd.Series(subject) # just a series of subject data

    #Sender
    sender = pd.Series(sender) # just a series of sender data

    #Body
    body = pd.Series(body) # just a series of sender data


    df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Start_Date':startDate,'Name':sender, 'Subject': subject, 'Body':body})
```

And this is my code to transfer them to my MS SQL:

```
    connStr = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};         Server=someservername;DATABASE=somedatabase;UID=someID;PWD=somepassword@')

    cursor = connStr.cursor()

    deleteTable = "DELETE FROM dbo.BSO_metricsEmailReports"

    cursor.execute(deleteTable)

    for index,row in df2.iterrows():
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO dbo.BSO_metricsEmailReports([Start_Date],    [Name],[Subject],    [Body])values(?,?,?,?)",row['Start_Date'],row['Name'],row['Subject'],row['Body']    )
    connStr.commit()
    cursor.close()
    connStr.close()

They would be sent to a table in my MS SQL 2014 with the below design:

    **Column Name**  |  **Data Type**
    Start_Date       |  datetime
    Name             |  nchar(300)
    Subject          |  nchar(300)
    Body             |  nchar(300)
```

Comment: Have you tried making the query params a sequence instead of a list of arguments, eg: `row['Start_Date'],row['Name'],row['Subject'],row['Body']` becomes: `[row['Start_Date'],row['Name'],row['Subject'],row['Body']]` - so it's a list containing four items as an argument to execute and not 4 arguments to execute?

Comment: just tried what you said, unfortunately it's still not working. My other program that extracts data from a database and transfers it to my data warehouse works. It seems that it's difficult when it is from outlook.

Answer (score 0):

I'd check the execute line...

I use the ? for each parameter in the query and set it up:

```
sql_rollup     = 
    '''
    SELECT        ID,FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, .USERNAME, numSessions
    FROM           SESSION INNER JOIN
                            PERSONNEL ON SESSION.ID = PERSONNEL.ID
    WHERE       (SessionStartDT between  ? AND ?) AND (SiteID = ?)
    '''
```

Then I execute the above like this:

```
 con = pyodbc.connect(
        Trusted_connection='Yes',
        Driver='{SQL Server}',
        Server=myConfig["database"]["hostname"] + ',' + myConfig["database"]["port"],
        Database=myConfig["database"]["database"]
    )

    con.autocommit = True
    cur=con.cursor()
    parms = (str(dateFirst), str(dateLast), siteID)

    cur.execute(sql_rollup,parms)
```

Note the params is set up as a list and also (and I suspect this is where the problem lies), I convert the datatime values for dateFirst and dateLast to strings.

pyodbc doesn't understand Python objects. The database on the otherhand can automatically interpret strings and convert them into date/time values.

Does this help?

Comment: apologies but I don't know how to adapt your lines to mine.

Comment: Giancarlo - if you look at my line where I define parms...

I make the dates a string but I also make them a list. Look also at what Jon Clements is telling you.

Define your sql as a separate string using the three single quotes. This makes it easier to deal with.

Make your parms into a list (see my code for how I've done this - use the braces around the items, substitute your own row[xxxxx] in there) and then pass that list into the cursor.execute line.

The error comes from passing a datetime object rather than a string.